# Is null or not an object in internet explorer but not in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, internet-explorer-8

When running a javascript code I get the following error in IE only "thisList.name    is null or not an object at line 297 character 2(the line with comment - tableTotal[thisList.name]=0)". It works just fine in Firefox though. Below is my code:

```
var groupTable = {};
var groupFS = {};
var tableTotal = {};
var grandTotal = 0;

$.each(allLists, function(index) {
     thisList=allLists[index];
     tableTotal[thisList.name]=0;//This line throw the error
     thisDiv=$("<div id='" +thisList.name+"'/>");

     fsString='<fieldset><legend>' + thisList.label;
     fsString+='<span class="legendneutral">';
     fsString+=' (span class="ui-button tableselect"  
          onclick="QtOptions.selectTable(this)">Select All&nbsp;</span>|'
     fsString+='<span class="ui-button tabledeselect" onclick
          ="QtOptions.deselectTable(this)>&nbsp;Deselect All)</span>)'
     fsString+='</span>
     fsString+='<legend></fieldset>' ;
     groupFS[thisList.name]=$(fsString);
     groupTable[thisList.name]=$("<table id='" +thisList.name+ "_table' class
        ='sortable' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'/>");
     tHead='<thead><tr style="font-size:12px;"><th style="width:6%;">Selected</th>
         </tr></thead>
     $(groupFS[thisList.name]).appendTo($(thisDiv));
     $(tHead).appendTo($(groupTable[thisList.name]));
     $(groupTable[thisList.name]).appendTo($(groupFS[thisList.name]));
     $(thisDiv).appendTo($(tabdiv));
     });
```

Comment: Although that line gives you an error, the real problem is not here -- it's likely when you're building `allLists`, which is not defined here. Please make a small, complete, self-contained demo that reproduces your issue.

Comment: what is `allLists`? does each and every one of the items in it have a `name` property?

Comment: What type is thisList expected to be? How did you populate allLists? My first guess would be that for some browser-specific reason, you've got one or more nulls in allLists.

Comment: I'm guessing `allLists` is an Array, and you left a trailing `,` after the last item. Some versions of IE will incorrectly add a member to the Array. This would cause the item to be iterated, and so `thisList.name` would be accessing `.name` on `undefined`.

Comment: The all lists was the problem. It was an array in a separate js file that I had commented out a couple of lines. Once I uncommented them out it worked just fine in IE. Thanks much everyone.

Comment: Be sure to answer your own question in that case.